# Numéro de téléphone du directeur

Tags: articles

I wonder why in “Numéro **de** téléphone **du** directeur”, on one occasion we use *de* and on the other *du*.

Why not *de* for both or *du* for both?

We would say “Numéro **de** téléphone **de** Papa” or “**de** l'ami” for instance. So does anybody know how to choose between *de* and *du* in those cases?

Answer (score 10):

As Evpok [says](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1380), *de* and *du* are not equivalent, and *du* is a contraction of *de le*.

So your question boils down to, when to use an article or not? Which is alas a more subtle question. Usually you would use the definite article when speaking about a definite instance; for example *le directeur* when speaking about one precise person, the headmaster of your school for example. If however you were speaking about headmasters in général, then you wouldn't use it. Contrast these two:

> *La voiture du* ("de le") *directeur.* (The headmaster's car)
>
> *Une voiture de directeur.* (A headmaster's car — meaning, a car worthy of a headmaster. I'm actually not sure there isn't a difference in English too. Maybe *a headmaster car*?).

The case of the phone number is similar: usually, one speaks about phone numbers in general, so you get *numéro de téléphone*. The expression becomes an entity of its own, so that you can use it even when speaking of one particular phone number. Contrast the following:

> *Un numéro de téléphone.* (a phone number)
>
> *Le numéro de téléphone du directeur.* (The headmaster's phone number)
>
> *Le numéro du téléphone du directeur.* (The number of the headmaster's phone — this is not actually incorrect, but the meaning is slightly different: here you focus on the phone, not the headmaster. If you were a technician repairing it, for instance, you might ask it that way.)

As for *papa*, as Evpok says, you wouldn't say *le papa* when speaking of your father. However, note that you would do it when speaking of someone else's father, as in:

> *Le numéro de téléphone de papa.* (Dad's phone number)
>
> *Le numéro de téléphone du* (again, "de le") *papa de Pierre.* (Pierre's dad's phone number)
>
> *Le numéro de téléphone du papa.* (The father's phone number — this isn't incorrect either, but you're speaking about the father of an unspecified person rather than your own. For instance, if you were a policeman having just found a lost kid, and you find the father's number in the kid's pockets. Although you'd more probably say *J'ai trouvé le numéro de téléphone du père* instead of using papa in this case.)

Comment: _Le numéro du téléphone du directeur_ is improbable, but specifying which phone make the use of _du_ not only possible, but mandatory: _le numéro du téléphone fixe du directeur_,  _le numéro du téléphone personnel du directeur_ or _le numéro du téléphone portable du directeur._

Comment: If you're saying that _le numéro de téléphone fixe du directeur_ is incorrect, I have to say that I disagree.

Comment: Plus *Le numéro du téléphone du directeur* doesn't seem improbable if there is no ambiguity.

Answer (score 6):

Actually *du* is not a form of *de*, but the contraction of *de* and *le*. In your example, one would normally say “*numéro de téléphone **de le** directeur*”, but to preserve the flow of the speech, the correct form is the contraction *du*.

For your second example, one would say *Papa* and not *le Papa*, so it is “*Numéro de téléphone **de** Papa*”.

The same phenomenon occurs with *au*, which is actually *à le*.